# Split and trim byte array

Tags: java, split, byte

I've a byte array contains some bytes separated by 7 and I want to split these bytes and then trim separated bytes. i.e.-14 must to remove from left and right of separated byte arrays.

> **Example:**
>
> input:  {-14, 2, 54, 23, -14, 7, 5, 73, 12, -14, -14, 7}
>   output: {2, 54, 23} , {5, 73, 12}
>
> input:  {34, 64, 23, -14, 43, -14, 7, 7, 42, 2, -14}
>   output: {34, 64, 23, -14, 43} ,  {42, 2}

**Edit**
Empty arrays should be removed. for example if 7 is in first or end of input array, it should be removed.

More example:

> input:  {7, 34,21,7}
>   output: {34,21}
>
> input:  {-14,-14,7,7,34,21,-14, 7,-14}
>   output: {34, 21}

**END EDIT**

Comment: What's special about -14? And in your second example, why don't you have an empty array between the two ones with content?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Empty arrays should be removed.

Comment: Any other requirements you haven't mentioned? Given that this is an unusual situation, you really should try to be exhaustive in your description. What about a 7 at the start of the input? Or empty input? Or input consisting just of 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over the array, maintaining an index `left` indicating the position of the last split. When you encounter a split location, or the end of the array, you take a second index `right` denoting that position. Now increase `left` and decrease `right` to trim the sequence. Then create a copy of the denoted subsequence.

```
int left = 0, right, pos;
for (pos = 0; pos <= a.length; ++pos) {
  if (pos < a.length && a[pos] != 7)
    continue; // no need to split, so simply go on
  for (right = pos; right != left; --right) // drop trailing -14s
    if (a[right - 1] != -14)
      break;
  // "right" now is one past the last element we want to keep
  for (; left != right; ++left) // drop leading -14s
    if (a[left] != -14)
      break;
  if (left != right) {
    byte[] b = new int[right - left];
    System.arraycopy(a, left, b, 0, right - left);
    res.add(b);
  }
  left = pos + 1;
}
```